# Android Studio update broke Gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I just updated my Android Studio 135.14 etc to 135.15.

First, I get an SDK not found error, since now the SDK cannot be in the Android Studio folder any more due to checksum problems. I fixed this as instructed, but now when I try to run my app I get the following message.

> Failed to complete Gradle execution.
>
> Cause: tried to access method
>   com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.()V from class
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.invoker.GradleTasksExecutor$3

I've already tried a clean and to delete .gradle from home. I don't see anything in build.gradle that has anything remotely to do with this and I am unsure on how to proceed.

I am not familiar with gradle at all since it just worked for months until the update.

Comment: Help > About. What's the display version number there? i.e. 0.8.13. Run gradle --version. Also what gradle tools version and `buildToolsVersion` are you using? These are in the two gradle build files in your project.

Comment: I "solved" it in a very unsatisfying way. First, I tried to copy a fresh install of AS over my current install. The problem remained. Then, I threw out my entire AS folder and made a new one. This worked. Presumably there was a generated properties file somewhere in the AS folder structure causing the error. It doesn't seem to be gradle related, it's just that gradle tries to build erroneous code in AS based on an old config file and thus it throws an error. If you encounter this, don't bother trying to solve it and download a fresh studio install of the latest version into a new folder.